# Flex 3 custom ItemRenderer and Editor Issue

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, uicomponents, itemeditor

I've created a custom ItemRenderer extending UIComponent and implementing IListItemRenderer. This renderer contains a Text-Object to display the value.

For editing I'm using the standard ItemEditor (TextInput).

Now, when I want to edit a value, I click on a cell and the editor is created. But instead of displaying the value which was displayed in the renderer, "[object Object]" is displayed.

Does someone know why and can help me out here? Would be awesome!

Comment: Post the relevant code. Have you specified `editorDataField`?

Comment: Posting relevant code is not that easy, since its completely generic and therefore a bit bulkier.. But I have managed my problem by writing my own editor and setting the text property to the relevant value on the dataChange event.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `labelField` of your itemRenderer is set to the data/object itself rather than the property of the object.  Make sure you have specified a `labelField` and that your `TextArea#text` property is set to `data.property` rather than `data`.  This is because

```
var data:Object = new Object();
data.label = "Hello";
trace(data); // "[object Object]"
trace(data.toString()); // "[object Object]" 
trace(data.label); // "Hello";
```

Hope that helps,
Lance